# Ruppig oder Hofton?

Tags: meaning

This is an extract from "... Als die Noten laufen lernten..." by Karin Ploog.

> Paul Lindau war in der großen Welt des Theaters zu Hause. Ihm sagte Heinrich Grünfeld eine unglaubliche Schaffenskraft nach. Man sah ihn überall mit seiner Zigarette im Mund; er saß nächtelang im Kaffeehaus oder in der Wirtsstube, trank wenig, aber rauchte und plauderte dafür umso mehr. Immer wenn er in eine Gesellschaft trat, fragte er nach der Stimmung: "Ruppig oder Hofton?"

I'm interested in how to precisely understand the connotations of "Ruppig oder Hofton?" For example, if I were to translate into English, would "formal or informal" capture the sense of this or is it more extreme? Does Hofton imply merely courteous or something more like courtly? Likewise, how far the other way does "ruppig" lean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"formal or informal" gets the meaning *more or less*, but not quite. The "Hof" in "Hofton" means an (imperial) court and the way people (presumedly) talk there. "Ruppig", on the other hand, is "gruff" or "abrasive" and the humour in this phrase comes from the (sarcastic) over-exaggeration of the opposites.

Yes,the opposites are perhaps as extreme as possible, but that is - as far as I can tell - just done for the humourous value and not really insinuating that there might not be some middle way. Suppose I'd ask you how you do financially in the words "Billionaire or homeless?".